# Iteratively print JavaScript dictionary of objects into HTML divs

Tags: javascript, html, generate

I'd appreciate some help with iteratively generating the beneath div based on the amount of items in a Javascript dictionary.

```
    <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="dropdown" style="padding: 10px;">
            <a href="#">TOP 3 PS5 HEADSETS<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <div id="links">

                    <center>
                        <p>3: &darr; INSERT TITLE FOR STEELSERIES &darr;</p>
                    </center>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="img/products/h-steelseries.png">
                        <a class="link" href="INSERT LINK HERE">Read More</a>
                    </div>

                    <center>
                        <p>3: &darr; INSERT TITLE FOR OTHER&darr;</p>
                    </center>
                    <div class="product">
                        <img src="img/products/h-other.png">
                        <a class="link" href="INSERT LINK HERE">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Beneath is the read.js file that contains the items in which I wish to generate the div class "product" for.

I'd really apprecaite any help with this.

```
var prod_obj = {
    "headphone_products" : {
        "title": "Steelseries",
        "IMAGE": "h-steelseries.png",
        "HREF" : "steelseries.html"
},
"other_products" : {
    "title": "Other product",
    "IMAGE": "h-other.png",
    "HREF" : "other.html"
}
};
```

I have looked at other answers and couldn't find an example of a dictionary of object that was used to automatically generate divs. I intend on using this to list items on a website and would like to append objects to the dictionary and them to automatically generate a new div for each object once the script is executed.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is that HTML all there is - it will not be repeated and you simply wish to populate that with values in the json data?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius apologies, that is what I'd like the output to be. I'd like that div to be generated for the second object in the dictionary and so on

Comment: So it would be repeated N times? It is the ID `links` thayt is the issue if so

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop over the object and create the desired nodes inside the loop.

Here's a simpler version of the same.

```js
var prod_obj = {
  "headphone_products": {
    "title": "Steelseries",
  },
  "other_products": {
    "title": "Other product",
  }
};

for (let keys in prod_obj) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = prod_obj[keys].title
  document.body.appendChild(div)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for-in loops and template literals to achieve what you want to achieve here.

```js
const prod_obj = {
  "headphone_products": {
    "title": "Steelseries",
    "image": "h-steelseries.png",
    "href": "steelseries.html"
  },
  "other_products": {
    "title": "Other product",
    "image": "h-other.png",
    "href": "other.html"
  }
};

const div = document.getElementById('insertHere');

for (let products_key in prod_obj) {
  let {title, image, href} = prod_obj[products_key];
  let html = `<p>Title: ${title}, Image: ${image}, href: ${href}</p>`;
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

```html
<div id="insertHere">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a suitable candidate for a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) which, according to the documentation on MDN says:

> The HTML Content Template () element is a mechanism for
> holding HTML that is not to be rendered immediately when a page is
> loaded but may be instantiated subsequently during runtime using
> JavaScript.

The following uses a simple class to load a new instance of the designated template for each product found within the source data ( what you refer to as a `dictionary` ). Once the template has been loaded from the shadows you can manipulate the contents as you wish. If you change the design of the template you change the design of the final layout. In the original HTML there is no `span` element surrounding the individual products but the way I wrote the template loader( for a specific job ) clones the `first` child element entirely - so a `span` will not affect layout unless styled specifically to do so.

```js
class TemplateLoader{
  constructor( id ){
    this.id=id;
    return this.create();
  };
  gettemplate(){
    return document.querySelector( 'template[ data-id="'+this.id+'" ]' ) || false
  };
  clone(){
    let tmpl=this.gettemplate();
    return tmpl ? tmpl.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode( true ) : false;
  };
  gettarget(){
    return document.querySelector( 'div[ id="'+this.id+'" ]' ) || false;
  };
  create(){
    let tmpl=this.clone();
    if( tmpl ){
      let target=this.gettarget();
        target.appendChild( tmpl );
      return tmpl;
    }
    return false;
  };
};

  var prod_obj = {
    'headphone_products' : {
      'title': 'steelseries',
      'image': 'h-steelseries.png',
      'href' : 'steelseries.html'
    },
    'other_products' : {
      'title': 'other product',
      'image': 'h-other.png',
      'href' : 'other.html'
    },
    'banana':{
      'title':'curvy & yellow',
      'image':'b-a-nana.png',
      'href':'banana.html'
    }
  };

  let id='links';

  Object.keys( prod_obj ).forEach( cat => {
    let data=prod_obj[ cat ];

    let oTmpl=new TemplateLoader( id );
      oTmpl.querySelector('center > p').textContent=data.title;
      oTmpl.querySelector('div.product > img').src=['img/products',data.image].join('/');
      oTmpl.querySelector('div.product > a.link').href=data.href;
  });
```

```html
<!-- regular HTML -->
<div class='container'>
  <div class='dropdown'>
    <a href='#'>TOP 3 PS5 HEADSETS<i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i></a>
    <ul>
      <div id='links'>
        <!-- items will be populated here -->
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>








<!-- our template that will be used to generate new content within the above, regular HTML' -->
<template data-id='links'>
  <span>
    <center>
      <p></p>
    </center>
    <div class='product'>
      <img />
      <a class='link'>Read More</a>
    </div>
  </span>
</template>
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Apologies for the double post - I sent it from my laptop as my pc blue screened and couldn't locate this post. It's my mistake but I accidentally posted the wrong dictionary - the one in the second post was the correct nesting.

Comment: In the `"other"` post the structure of the data is quite different to that shown here. How is that structure supposed to be used with the given HTML here? This new data has no image references - are they now redundant?

Comment: I was using the image references as an example. I just needed it so I could add extra values to the objects if i wanted to in the future.

Comment: It's not clear how your new data structure should work with regards to the above. Does it matter that there are multiple top-level objects each containing products - should each product be added as before or is there special requirements in terms of layout. This is not clearly defined.

Comment: Incidentally I have just noticed that your markup is snafu... You cannot nest a `div` as a direct child of `ul` elements but it is possible to nest `div` elements within a `li` element

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to add content to the DOM on-the-fly is to use a series of calls to **[`createElmenent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)** (which is less error-prone than just inserting HTML strings).  And you can **loop through your data object's keys and extract the details** you need to configure your new DOM elements. This script does both of these things in a function called `updateDOM`, which invokes the `appendProductDetails` function once per product.

I changed the hrefs to create functional (if arbitrary) links, and of course the images don't show up because they don't exist on StackOverflow's server. See the in-code comments for further explanation.

```js
const currentProds = getProductsToShow();
updateDOM(currentProds);

function updateDOM(prod_obj) {

  // Identifies parent div
  const linksDiv = document.getElementById("links");

  // Clears parent div
  linksDiv.innerHTML = "";

  // Loops through productName (keys) in prod_obj
  const productNames = Object.keys(prod_obj);
  for (let productName of productNames) {

    // Gets details (inner object) for each product
    const details_obj = prod_obj[productName];

    // Creates, configures, and appends new elements for each product
    appendProductDetails(linksDiv, details_obj);
  }
}

function appendProductDetails(parentElement, detailsObject) {
  const
  // Gets local copies of values via "destructuring"
  { title, image, href } = detailsObject,
  path = "img/products/", // Defines path to images

    // Creates elements to add to the DOM
    productDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    titleP = document.createElement("p"),
    img = document.createElement("img"),
    anchor = document.createElement("a");

  // Configures newly created elements
  productDiv.classList.add("product");
  titleP.textContent = title;
  img.src = path + image;
  img.alt = image;
  anchor.classList.add("link");
  anchor.href = href;
  anchor.textContent = "Read More";

  // Puts children into productDiv
  productDiv.appendChild(titleP);
  productDiv.appendChild(img);
  productDiv.appendChild(anchor);

  // Attaches everything to the DOM
  parentElement.appendChild(productDiv);
}

// Provides demo data
function getProductsToShow() {
  const productsObj = {
    "headphone_products": {
      "title": "Steelseries",
      "image": "h-steelseries.png", // In img/products/
      "href": "https://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "other_products": {
      "title": "Other product",
      "image": "h-other.png",
      "href": "https://eloquentjavascript.net/"
    }
  };
  return productsObj;
}
```

```css
.container{ width: 250px; text-align: center; }
.dropdown > a{ text-decoration: none; }
p{ margin: -0.1rem 0; font-size: 1.2rem; }
.product{ padding: 0.5rem ; }
.link{ margin-left: 1rem; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">PS5 HEADSETS</a>
    <div id="links"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(A more modern approach would be to repeatedly clone the contents of a [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) element and to use `slot` elements to insert corresponding product details into each new instance.)